# Typechecking value before adding it to a vector

Tags: c++, templates

At one point in my code I have to add values to a helper vector. The following is a simplification of what is going on.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template<typename A, typename B>
void add_value(std::vector<A> vec, B val) {
    if (std::is_same<A, B>::value) {
        vec.push_back(val);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> vec = {};
    std::string val = "Hello!";
    add_value(vec, val);

    return 0;
}
```

The issue I'm having is that I want to add a value to a vector conditionally. The condition being that the types are the same. Even though this works out logically, the program doesn't compile: 
`error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<int>::push_back(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)’`

What solutions are there to this sort of problem?

Comment: Why even have `B` as a template parameter instead of `void add_value(std::vector<A> vec, B val)`? Is the intention that `add_value(std::vector<int>, std::string)` should compile but be a no-op?

Comment: @NathanPierson That is the intention, yes. This is a simplified version, so the full context isn't clear. In short I want to add values to a vector unless the value isn't the vector's type, but I don't necessarily know what those values are. So if I do end up calling the function, I need to make sure it's a no-op.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [constexpr if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) (since C++17).

> If the value is `true`, then *statement-false* is discarded (if present), otherwise, *statement-true* is discarded.

```
template<typename A, typename B>
void add_value(std::vector<A>& vec, B val) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same<A, B>::value) {
        vec.push_back(val);
    }
}
```

BTW: `vec` should be passed by-reference, otherwise it'll be a copy and modification on it has nothing to do with the original argument.

Comment: I would also pass `val` by (const) reference, too. That can avoid making copies of the input unless `push_back()` is actually being called.